# nginx: [emerg] "server" directive is not allowed

Tags: ubuntu, http, nginx, debian, google-cloud-platform

Actualmente, tengo un servidor en Google Cloud utilizando instancias de VM con **NGINX** para transmisiones (**streaming**). La conexión está funcionando correctamente, y puedo enviar video de un punto A a un punto B.

Sin embargo, al intentar agregar las siguientes líneas al archivo **nginx.conf**, me encuentro con un error al verificar la sintaxis. El mensaje de error específico que recibo es el siguiente:

```
nginx: [emerg] "server" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:87 
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

## Configuración para el servidor HTTP

Líneas agregadas aquí:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 34.121.43.17;

    location / {
        root /var/www/html;
        index index.nginx-debian.html;
    }
}
```

Fin de lineas agregadas aquí:

```
rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935;
        chunk_size 4000;

        application live {
            live on;
            record off;
        }
    }
}
```

Soy nuevo en esto es mi primera vez configurando algo así
Saludos Espero su ayuda.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! como es tu archivo de configuracion completo?? eso, no parece correcto..

Comment: Tienes instalado el modulo rtpm para nginx?